# Trying to send one approval email or a Denied Email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Below is the code that I'm trying to use, the problem is that when I select the approved option from the menu it will send the denied email, it will only send the denied email in fact. can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Both functions do appear in the menu but when I click on approved it only sends the denied email.

```
function menuItem1(){
 const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 const row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
 Logger.log(row);
 const data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,1,6).getValues()[0];
 const user = {
    name : data[1],
    email : data[4],
    row : row
 } 
  Logger .log(user);
  const res = ui.alert('Send To '+user.name+'('+user.email+')?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(res == ui.Button.YES){
   sendUser(user);
  }
  Logger.log(res);
}
function sendUser(user){
  
  const temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ApprovedEmail.html');
  temp.user = user;
  const message = temp.evaluate().getContent();
  

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: user.email,
    subject : 'Vacation Request',
    htmlBody : message,
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(user.row,6).setValue('Sent Email with Approval');
}
 
function menuItem2(){
 const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 const row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
 Logger.log(row);
 const data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,1,6).getValues()[0];
 const user = {
    name : data[1],
    email : data[4],
    row : row
 }
 
  Logger .log(user);
  const res = ui.alert('Send To '+user.name+'('+user.email+')?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(res == ui.Button.YES){
   sendUser(user);
  }
  Logger.log(res);
}

function sendUser(user){
  
  const temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DeniedEmail.html');
  temp.user = user;
  const message = temp.evaluate().getContent();


  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: user.email,
    subject : 'Vacation Request',
    htmlBody : message,
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(user.row,6).setValue('Dinied Email Sent');
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the google sheet that I'm trying to send the email from.

[that's the Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8ZKN.png)

Comment: Your code is kind of a mess and you have two functions with the same name.  Every function must have a unique name.  You should probably review how to make a menu.

Comment: I have changed the name for both functions to be unique before, but I can only get one to work. the one you see is the last thing I tried.

Comment: You still have two functions named sendUser()

Comment: thank you Cooper, I just knew it was going to be simple but I'm new at this. thank you that fix it.